# Reading the same element twice with EclipseLink MOXy

Tags: java, xpath, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

Is it possible to read the same element into two different Java properties using EclipseLink MOXy?

In the below example I'm mapping the `<publication>` document as a class, and the `<date>` element as Java class with an `XmlAdapter` that's a propert of my publication object. I'd also like to have the `year` element set as a *separate* property of the Publication class, *as well as* part of the compound `Date` class I've made. However, when I set this up in the XML bindings, year alone is always null, but the date gets populated properly.

```
<publication>
    <date datetype="OriginalPub">
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>Feb.</month>
        <day>0</day>
    </date>
</publication
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) does not support the XPath for mapping one classes properties to dip into the portion of an XML document that is mapped to another class.  You could leverage an `afterUnmarshal` event to pull the year from the date object and set it on the publication object.

```
package forum13122968;

import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Publication {

    Date date;
    int year;

    private void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) {
        year = date.getYear();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Blaise, I'd just tried that out. Really liking MOXy so far, and very grateful for your prompt answers on here!